# Slick carousel - display carousel inside a boxed div

Tags: css, slick.js

I'm using [slick carousel](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/) and i think it's a really nice library.

However, I'm facing an issue with the templates i need to achieve.

Basically, i need the slick carousel to display partially next and prev slides (which can be done adding some property when slick is initialised) but the issue is that i need my carousel to be with specific dimensions.

So, the carousel needs to be placed inside a boxed div of 1200px (the main slide need to be 1200 width and keep the height as auto so that i doesn't deform) and the partial slides to be extended to the edge of the screen.

Here's a quick example on code pen (2 approaches, so check the comments to see them both): https://codepen.io/nickimola/pen/xrRraW

Markup:

**html**

```
<div class="carousel-container">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/960/442/?image=0" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/960/442/?image=10" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/960/442/?image=11" />
</div>
```

**Less css**

```
.carousel-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 442px;
  img {
    max-width:1200px;
  }
}
```

**Coffeescript**

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('.carousel-container').slick({
    infinite: true,
    centerPadding: '60px',
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
    centerMode: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000
  })
```

Obviously, the solution needs to be clean and nothing hacky (modify library files *is not* a solution.

I'm also using bootstrap if it can help a bit.

Thanks for any help or suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys i think i got it.

Here's the updated code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="carousel-container">
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1200/442/?image=0" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1200/442/?image=10" />
  <img src="https://unsplash.it/1200/442/?image=11" />
</div>
```

**LESS**

```
img{
    max-width:1200px;
    width:1200px;
}

.slick-slide{
    opacity: 0.6;
    &.slick-current{
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

**CoffeeScript**

```
$(document).ready ->
  $('.carousel-container').slick({
    infinite: true,
    centerPadding: '60px',
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    centerMode: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    variableWidth: true // This one did the trick!
  })
```

So apparently it turned out that if I allow from slick properties to have a variable width, the width can be specified correctly using CSS.

If you check now the example you can see what i mean: https://codepen.io/nickimola/pen/xrRraW